# Enable a process to fire without editing it

Tags: process-builder, process

I'm trying to create a process that will create a task when a specified date field = today(), which doesn't seem to work.

Use Case.  Opportunity is closed/won.  After the agreement is signed and all business processes are done, a "go live date" field enters a value (for when the spcified office tentatively becomes a partner).  I want to set the process to fire when the "go_live_Date__c = TODAY()", which would then create a task to the relationship manager.

What I'm finding out is that unless the opp is saved with the "go live date" of "today" (not a future date), it won't fire off the task.

I tried to modify the process by giving the criteria of:

Status = Closed Won &&
go_live_Date__c != false

at which point, do a time based workflow to fire off when the "go_live_Date__c" is 0 hours from the go_live_date value.  But that didn't work either.

Is this possible?

Comment: You will need a DML event (i.e. an edit) to fire any workflow/trigger/process. Sounds like you want either a time based workflow rule/process builder. So when go_live_Date__c != null schedule the action on the date entered into go_live_Date__c

Answer (score 2):

You definitely need a time-based workflow for this. You set the due date to the to the go_live_Date__c

Your criteria will be Status = Closed Won && go_live_Date__c != null

That was as long as the status is Closed Won and there is a date in the go live then it will fire on the date that the go live field is set for.

What happens with time-based workflow is that they re-evaluate at the time they are due to trigger so if for whatever reason your status is no longer closed won then it won't fire, which is quite useful.

Comment: +1, though process builder can do this, too.

Comment: I'm constantly pulling rookie mistakes.  It didn't work yesterday since I didn't create a new opp after updating the process.  Created a new one today and saw the process in flows pending, so I should be good!